# swift: uicollectionview changes contentoffset of the cell during transition

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple UICollectionView with a custom cell inside of a navigationController. For some reason when I push a viewController, the collectionView cell changes its layout during the transition.

Is it some common behavior of uicollectionview during viewController transition? Because, for example: labels don't have such problem

[When back button was clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va9Ek.png)
Green color from collectionView

Adding new view controller

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Setting Autolayout using [EasyPeasy](https://github.com/nakiostudio/EasyPeasy) pod

```
collectionView.easy.layout([
  Top(),
  Right(),
  Width(view.frame.width),
  Bottom(10).to(button),
])

button.easy.layout([
  Center(),
  Height(60),
  Width(300),
])
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to do with these constraints but you are not using any height for the collectionview. Which i think is being calculated by the button. As it looks the green collectionview is being set to 10px(maybe?).. When do you set the constraints in your code? And what's that blue box, and the constraints for that element? Feels like there is some problem with your autolayout anyways..

Comment: @MartinBorstrand UICollectionViewCell's backgroundColor is blue. I set constraints in viewDidLoad. I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Seems like during transitioning back cell gets smaller

Comment: Okej, do you set the size of the cell then? How does that look?

Comment: @MartinBorstrand return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: collectionView.bounds.height) inside collectionView(:sizeForItemAt). As I already added above, this behavior takes place only for collectionView cells

Comment: @MartinBorstrand here is the video https://youtu.be/KHaJm9vS3cs

Comment: It looks like there is a animation activated somewhere. The transition seems to be changing the pushing views content in some way. Dont know if it has something to do with your EasyPeasy pod or something. You can upload your classes on dropbox or something if you want. Would be easier to understand the problem then.

Comment: @MartinBorstrand Here is the whole project https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9lv32ptq9wzp2h/cv%2BlargeImages.zip?dl=0. It seems like the animation takes place only when collectionView located at the top. No animation when it's at the center :/

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found your problem and it's in you AppDelegate. The property `isTranslucent` which is set to false to your navigation controller seems to cauese this rare problem. A translucent navigation bar will be on top of your viewcontroller's view, like above it. A non-translucent navigation bar pushes down your view controller's view or in other words rezising it so it fits beneath it.. But why the collectionview animates like it does is something I actually cant give a definite answer about. Maybe someone else could do that?..

To keep your navigation bar translucent you can set another property in your viewcontroller which is ´extendedLayoutIncluedsOpaqueBars´ to true.

So.. Do like this. In your AppDelegate:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
let controller = TestingNavigationController()
let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
window!.rootViewController = navigation

let navigationBarAppereance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navigationBarAppereance.isTranslucent = false
```

Then, in your view controllers viewDidLoad method add this line

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

Hope this will solve your problem! :)

[Apple Documentation about extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621404-extendedlayoutincludesopaquebars)

Comment: @Dauren would you please react on my answer?